# How do i block user access to a directory using java?

Tags: java, security, directory, file-permissions

Is it possible with java to modify directory permission so that no one can access the content inside that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method on the `File` object for this

- [`boolean setWritable(boolean writable, boolean ownerOnly)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean,%20boolean))
- [`boolean setReadable(boolean readable, boolean ownerOnly)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean,%20boolean))
- [`boolean setExecutable(boolean executable,boolean ownerOnly)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean,%20boolean))

```
File dir = new File("my directory");
dir.mkdir();

// Make it not readable, writable and executable for anyone
dir.setExecutable(false, false);
dir.setReadable(false, false);
dir.setWritable(false, false);

// Make it readable, writable and executable for the owner only (see
// second parameter "ownerOnly" to these calls)
dir.setExecutable(true, true);
dir.setReadable(true, true);
dir.setWritable(true, true);
```

The Java NIO API has more fine-grained controls to do the same, such as

- [`Path setPosixFilePermissions(Path path, Set<PosixFilePermission> perms)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set))

Comment: I can access the folder after the following code execution.
`dir.setExecutable(false, false);
dir.setReadable(false, false);
dir.setWritable(false, false);
`